# ASP.NET MVC 2.0 application not working on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 2.0 application that is only loading the Home Index page. Whenever I try to navigate away from the page I get a HTTP Error 404 - File or directory not found.
Internet Information Services (IIS).

The site works find While testing on a localhost but whenever I try to run it on the destination site I keep not being able to navigate away from the Home page.

This is the way I am currently trying to get into the LoginOut Controller and trying to run the login method.

```
<% var login = Url.Action("Login", "LogInOut"); %>
<form method="post" class="pure-form" action="<% Response.Write(login); %>">
```

Then the LoginOutController is suppose to run this code. However no code get's run as the page both doesn't redirect and there is no Log file of what has just happened.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        var username = Request.Form["username"];
        var password = Request.Form["password"];
        SessionFacade.UserSession = UserQueries.GetUserSession(username, password);
        UserSession us = SessionFacade.UserSession;

        //redirects to login if us is null
        if (us == null)
        {
            Log.InvalidLogin(us, username);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else if (us.GetUploader())
        {
            var uploadedFiles = new SessionFilesUploaded();
            Session[SessionValue.SessionFilesUploaded()] = uploadedFiles;
        }

        Log.UserLogin(us);

        //Checks that each user type has an appropriate folder and makes folders that are missing
        var folders = UserQueries.GetFolders();
        FolderExist.MakeFolder(folders);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Browser");
    }
```

The URL that I end up getting the 404 error is LogInOut/Login. Which as I said earlier works on my localhost server but doesn't seem to work on the webserver.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It would help to know what version of IIS is being used and on what OS this is hosted. ;)

Comment: Also, if this is a new development have you considered ASP.NET MVC 4 or even 5?

Comment: I am not sure what version of IIS and version of windows we are using. I originally wrote it in MVC 4.0 but the server that we have only supports .NET 3.5 so it would seem that 2.0 is the highest I can go.

Comment: This is what I get when I look on the server for the OS. 
psa v8.6.0.5_build20080722.15 os_Windows 2003/2008

Comment: Have you looked into doing a 'bin deploy'?

Comment: @jparram I have the System.Web.Abstractions, System.Web.MVC and System.Web.Routing included in the bin directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the issue was with the fact that we are running an old server and IIS6. The MVC requests aren't getting processed as ASP.NET and that's what causing the issues. Had to port the code from MVC to webforms.